# Android studio android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Tags: android, android-fragments, gradle

i am programing a menu to my app using fragmants.
I get the following error :
"Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.liadrosenberg.application.MenuActivitys.MyAccountActivity', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' more..."

I added

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
```

to my build.gradel file. Nothing had chhanged.
the problems only happens on the nav_Account menu.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

     if (id == R.id.nav_Gates) {
        FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.Count,new MyGatesActivity()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Settings) {
         FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.Count,new SettingsActivity()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Account) {
         FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.Count,new MyAccountActivity()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_About) {
         FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.Count,new SettingsActivity()).commit();
    }
```

the my account activity:

```
package com.example.liadrosenberg.application.MenuActivitys;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.liadrosenberg.application.R;

public class MyAccountActivity extends Fragment {
    @Override
    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_account, container, false);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MyAccountActivity` use `Fragment` from Support Library.

Use this import:

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`